# segmentation fault SIGSEGV dependant on initialisation method

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I wrote a small function `foo` that changes a string.

When I use the function, sometimes I receive a SIGSEGV-fault.  This is dependent on how the string is initialized.  In the calling function `main`, a string is initialized through memory allocation and calling `strcpy`.  I can change that string correctly.

The other string (`TestString2`) is initialized when I declared the variable.  I cannot trim this string but get the SIGSEGV-fault.

Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



void foo(char *Expr)
{
    *Expr = 'a';
}



int main()
{
    char  *TestString1;
    char  *TestString2 = "test   ";

    TestString1 = malloc (sizeof(char) * 100);
    strcpy(TestString1, "test   ");

    foo(TestString1);
    foo(TestString2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C does not have a string type. And a pointer is not an array!

Comment: @xing, Re "*TestString2 points to a string literal*", No, it points to a string. A string [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) is source code that represents a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of `TestString2`, you set it to the address of a string constant.  These constants cannot be modified, and typically reside in a read-only section of memory.  Because of this, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case manifests as a crash.

The case of `TestString1` is valid because it points to dynamically allocated memory which you are allowed to change.